# iPad : UITableView issue

Tags: ipad, uitableview, crash

I'm relatively new to iOS programming but with descent amount of programming experience in other languages, mainly C# and Java.

Im trying to make something like a picture gallery with specified categories for some product for an iPad device.
The UI is pretty simple made from a "Selection screen" (FirstViewController, see below) and "Gallery". Selection screen contains 2 UITableViews, `master` and `detail` which displays categories of product and a sub-categories, respectively. When the user do the selection it taps a "see picture" `button` and the pictures are displayed in scroll view in "Gallery". "Gallery" is a separate XIB file which is presented modally. That all works fine.

But, strange thing happens when user switches back and forth between "Gallery" and "Selection Screen". And the odd thing is that it happens exactly on 4th "switching" between them.
I keep getting the message :

**-[FirstViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x4b1f9f0"**

Then the program crashes...
I've set NSAutoreleaseFreedObjectCheckEnabled, NSZombiesEnabled and NSDebugEnabled and still no closer description. Even "Guard malloc" didn't help.

I understand this as some memory issue but have no idea why ? Works perfectly 3 times, but not the 4th.

Heres the part of code that causes trouble :

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    //check which table (master or detail) row is clcked then perform click event
    if( tableView.tag == 0){
        //populate list of brands using predefined function
        [self populateBrandNames:(int)indexPath.row];

        //reload data
        [detail reloadData];

        //4 a good UI experience we'll remove any previous picture loaded into brandImage
        bUserSelected = false;
        [brandImage setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }else{    //the detail table sent event
        NSIndexPath *master_row, *details_row;

        //get selected rows
        master_row = [master indexPathForSelectedRow];
        details_row = [detail indexPathForSelectedRow];

        NSString *logoName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%02d%02d_logo", (int)master_row.row, (int)details_row.row];
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:logoName ofType:@"jpg"];

        //check if we have path to resource (if logo exsist)
        if( path != nil ){
            UIImage *logo = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

            //display selected logo
            bUserSelected = true;
            [brandImage setBackgroundImage:logo forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            NSLog(@"brandImame set");

            //set current galery tag
            [currentGaleryTag setString:@""];
            [currentGaleryTag appendFormat:@"%02d%02d", (int)master_row.row, (int)details_row.row];
            [logo release];
        }else{
            NSLog(@"logo not loaded, galery tag : %@, category name : %@", logoName, [detail cellForRowAtIndexPath:details_row].textLabel.text );
        }

        [logoName release];
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

After a while i figured out whats causing the problem...

The point is, that in this particular app the "Gallery" is called modally.
Apple suggest that when using modal views, the caller (main view that handles displaying) must also take care of dismissing that same view.
The best metod to use in this scenario is using the "custom" protocol that describes a `delegate` and something like a `viewWillBeDismissed` method.

In my code that one looks like this :

```
@protocol ModalViewControllerDelegate 

- (void)didDismissModalView;

@end

@interface Galery : UIViewController {
    //outlets declaration
    ...

    //some other declarations here...

    //delegate reference
    id delegate;
}

//outlets and views properties
@property (nonatomic, assign) id delegate;

@end
```

Whats been causing the trouble is this line :

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id delegate;
```

The "only" thing that would need to be changed is this

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) id delegate;
```

Retaining a delegate reference is whats been solving an issue...

Cheers !